# How to play a sound file in Debian Python?

Tags: python, linux, audio, debian

sorry if this is a bit noobish but it's my first post. I am trying to open a .wav file (could be any though) in Python, on Debian Linux (on my raspberry Pi) I can't find any soloution that actually works, most modules are too old and don't work. I would preferablly like it to be as simple as possible. I just want the Python script to automatically play a sound file with the default audio player.

Comment: pygame and lots of other will work

Comment: There's a similar question (with an answer) for the Pi [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7088/playing-audio-files-with-python).

Answer (score 0):

Pyglet should work. Something like this:

```
    import pyglet

    sound = pyglet.resource.media('file.wav', streaming=False)
    sound.play()
```

I dont think it is preinstalled on the pi, but it's less than 1mb.